# Return elements that appear only once in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array and my goal is to return unique elements. I wrote the code that sorts an array and stores unique elements in ArrayList, but instead of returning only `[7]` it returns `[2,5,7]`. Why so?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int [] arr = {2, 5, 14, 14, 2, 7, 5};
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for (int i =0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
        if(arr[i]!=arr[i+1]){
            list.add(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: use a `Set` and do not have to sort (or maybe lambda with distinct)

Comment: You need to check `arr[i-1]` as well as `arr[i+1]` (and handle the end points).

Comment: @Andy that gets _distinct_ elements, not elements that only appear once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're allowed to use a Frequency Map, maybe you can try building a frequency map of all value in the array and then iterate of map entries and add all items with value == 1:

```java
// A map with key as array digit and value as it's frequency
Map<Integer, Integer> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
int [] arr = {2, 5, 14, 14, 2, 7, 5};

// Build Frequency Map
for (int j : arr)
    frequencyMap.merge(j, 1, Integer::sum);

// Add all items with frequency = 1 to list
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> intToFrequency : frequencyMap.entrySet()) {
    if (intToFrequency.getValue() == 1) {
        list.add(intToFrequency.getKey());
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Beacause when you sort original array you will get `{2,2,5,5,7,14}` and you are comparing adjacent elements, so in first iteration you are comparing `2` and `2` ie elements at index `0` and `1`, and since they are equal, you won't add element at index `0` into resulting list, but then in second iteration you are comparing `2` and `5` (element at positon `1` and `2`) and since they are not equal `2` will be added into resulting list. There is no need to do it like that, you can simply create `Set<Integer> result` from `arr` and since `Set` doesn't allow duplicate elements, your problem is solved. So you can write something like this :

```
Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use an array to store the *frequency* of each element in the array and add those elements whose frequency is 1 (unique elements) to the `list`.

```java
int max = Arrays.stream(arr).max().getAsInt();
int [] freq = new int[max+1];
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    ++freq[ arr[i] ];
for (int e : arr)
    if (freq[ e ] == 1)
        list.add( e );
System.out.println(list);
```

Please note this will work only when `max` is not very large (<10^8). If array contains larger values then you can use a `HashMap` in a similar fashion to store the frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

No need to count frequency.

If array elements can be present at most  twice there's a very simple approach using a single `Set`. For each array member, if it's not in set add it, if it is remove it. You'll be left with the unique elements.

```
Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();
for(int i : arr)
{
    if(seen.contains(i)) 
        seen.remove(i);
    else 
        seen.add(i);
}
```

If elements can appear more than twice you'll need a 2nd `Set`

```
Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();
for(int i : arr)
{
    if(unique.contains(i)) 
    {
        unique.remove(i);
        seen.add(i);
    }
    else if(!seen.contains(i))
    {
        unique.add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you sort your array you get [2,2,5,5,7,14,14]. In your for loop you only check if the element after it is different. When i=1, arr[1]!=arr[2] hence arr[1] is added even though 2 is not a unique element. Instead check if the value before and after it are different. You might have to change the indexing on your for loop.

An alternative is that you could create a set which only stores unique values. And loop through the array once adding each value to the set. The set will store all unique values. You can then convert the set to an ArrayList if your method must return and ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

you put every number in the array in 2 different pairs, you should change the indexes in the if statement in the loop so that every value in the array is part of 1 pair.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but over complicating it.

It's much easier to create a dictionary / hash map, and whilst iterating over your array, if the value is not in your hash map, store it.

We use a dictionary / hash map, because it provides us with a constant lookup time.

At the end of the iteration, your dictionary / hash map will contain all your unique values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Existing code of detecting duplicate values in a sorted array needs to be changed slightly to skip the duplicate values with the help of a boolean flag and a nested loop:

```java
public static List<Integer> getUnique(int ... arr) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
    
    System.out.print("Input: " + Arrays.toString(arr) + " -> ");

    Arrays.sort(arr);
    
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        boolean dupFound = false;
        for (j = i + 1; j < arr.length && arr[i] == arr[j]; j++) {
            dupFound = true;
            i = j;
        }
        if (dupFound) {
            continue;
        }
        list.add(arr[i]);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Tests:

```java
System.out.println(getUnique(2, 5, 14, 14, 2, 7, 5));
System.out.println(getUnique(2, 5, 14, 14, 20, 7, 7, 5, 14));
```

Output:

```
Input: [2, 5, 14, 14, 2, 7, 5] -> [7]
Input: [2, 5, 14, 14, 20, 7, 7, 5, 14] -> [2, 20]
```

If it is allowed to use `Set`, this task can be resolved without pre-sorting the input array and using two sets: one to track distinct values and the other to track *unique* values based on the fact that `Set::add` returns true if the element has not been included in the set and `false` if there is a duplicate in the set:

```java
public static Set<Integer> getUnique(int ... arr) {
    Set<Integer> distinct = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<>();
    
    System.out.print("Input: " + Arrays.toString(arr) + " -> ");
    
    for (int x : arr) {
        if (distinct.add(x)) { // no duplicate found yet
            unique.add(x);     // count as unique
        } else {
            unique.remove(x);  // remove a duplicate
        }
    }
    return unique;
}
```

The tests and their results are the same as shown above.